# Install and use Material UI (MUI) with Inertia from @adonisjs/inertia: 1.0.0-18 #132

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, inertiajs, adonisjs-ace

I am trying out the new features from AdonisJS with Inertia and ReactJS, on the ReactJS ecossystem MUI is a very popular UI library that provides all sorts of components.

Steps I followed:
I created a new project, using the default Inertia template provided by the adonisjs installer. The project runs, I am able to access the routes and so on.

Installed MUI in NodeJS in NodeJS v18 it is ok; installed in NodeJS 20 it is also ok, but even when the library installs on node_modules I cannot import the components into my TSX files.

The VSCode doesn't recognize it and even when I add the import by hand It does not work properly.